# Tag structure initialization failed, tag structure is ignored, it might be corrupted

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7, tagged-pdf

I created a fillable PDF using Adobe Acrobat pro and tagged the input fields.  Tagged Content, Tagged annotations, Tagged Form Fields passed in the Accessibility check for the document I am trying to fill using itext. I am getting this error when i am trying to fill the document from java code using itext library.

```
ERROR com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument - Tag structure initialization failed, tag structure is ignored, it might be corrupted.
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: StructParent index not found in tagged object.
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagging.ParentTreeHandler.registerMcr(ParentTreeHandler.java:182)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagging.ParentTreeHandler.registerAllMcrs(ParentTreeHandler.java:266)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagging.ParentTreeHandler.<init>(ParentTreeHandler.java:104)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagging.PdfStructTreeRoot.<init>(PdfStructTreeRoot.java:82)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.tryInitTagStructure(PdfDocument.java:1937)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1709)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:293)
              at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:261)
```

pdf link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KO772GQbolJ0oNMAzsdGPrLqfUtRcKbs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Which iText 7 version exactly do you use? I tested opening it with the current 7.1.14 and could do so without any problem.

Comment: I am using 7.0.7

Comment: Have you tried updating? Probably itext meanwhile has been hardened against such problem pdfs.

Comment: I did try using the latest version(7.1.14 too), but still had the same problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with iText 7.2.5 and this document: https://www.fda.gov/media/166704/download

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the field tags and retagged the whole documents using "Autotag form fields" in the "Accessibility" menu. This fixed the issue.